# Consecutive numbers which use all digits a different number of times

Tags: mathematics, number-theory

Are there arbitrarily long sets of consecutive numbers such that when writing the set down, every single digit (0 to 9) is used a different number of times?

Comment: Define Arbitrarily long

Comment: @Ankit: As long as I wish.

Comment: And what does that mean? @BernardoRecamánSantos

Comment: @Ankit; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrarily_large

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes.

> To get a consecutive string of $10^n$ numbers with different digit counts, just take your starting point to be "122333444455555666666777777788888888999999990...0", with $n$ zeroes at the end.
>
>  In your $10^n$ numbers, the last digits will just count up from $1$ to $10^n$. Each of those positions will be any chosen value exactly a tenth of the time. So, since the prefixes are consistently *unequally* distributed, and the suffixes balance out to become equally distributed, the total count of all the digits will be unequally distributed.
>  
>   (Specifically, the digit $d$ will appear $10^{n-1}+d10^{n}$ times.)

Comment: Beat me! I think the sequence of numbers from $1$ to $10000...00987654321$ will also satisfy this for a sufficiently large number of zeroes.

Comment: In that case it would be interesting to find which is the least N such that a different number of each of the ten digits is used to write down numbers 1, 2, 3, ..., N.

Comment: @BernardoRecamánSantos Assuming I'm interpreting this correctly, I don't think you can go lower than 100000000011111112222222333333444445555666778.  That's zero 9s, one 8, two 7s, etc., up to eight 1s and nine 0s, front-loading the smallest values in the most significant digits.  If we're allowed to count leading 0s, you could make that 000000000111111112222222333333444445555666778, which is a lot smaller.  If you require each digit to be used at least once, then it's 1000000000011111111222222223333333444444555556666777889 or 0000000000111111111222222223333333444444555556666777889

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: I mean writing down all the numbers from 1 to N, not just N.

Comment: The matter has now been settled: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3652336/smallest-n-such-that-writing-down-integers-1-to-n-uses-a-different-number-of-eac/3652645#3652645

Answer (score 6):

Yes.

> I believe this that is true with binary numbers starting from 1:
>
>  `number  [total ones, total zeros]`
>  `1       [1,0]`
>  `10      [2,1]`
>  `11      [4,1]`
>  `100     [5,3]`
>  `101     [7,4]`
>
>  The number of 0's will never catch up to the number of 1's.

Comment: Welcome Shawn! Nice start!